# Command to execute where subfolders contain '.csv'

Tags: command-line, bash

This is my folder structure:

```
ORDERNO'S  YEAR'S  MONTH'S  DATE'S  CSVFILES
408------->2010---->01-->21--->1.CSV
                           --->2.CSV
                      --->22--->1.CSV
                           --->2.CSV
               ----->02-->21--->1.CSV
                           --->2.CSV
                      --->22--->1.CSV
                           --->2.CSV
               ...
    ------->201101-->21--->1.CSV
                           --->2.CSV
                      --->22--->1.CSV
                           --->2.CSV
               ----->02-->21--->1.CSV
                           --->2.CSV
                      --->22--->1.CSV
                           --->2.CSV
    ------->201201-->21--->1.CSV
                           --->2.CSV
                      --->22--->1.CSV
                           --->2.CSV
               ----->02-->21--->1.CSV
                           --->2.CSV
                      --->22--->1.CSV
                           --->2.CSV
               ...
    ------->2013--01-->21--->1.CSV
                           --->2.CSV
                      --->22--->1.CSV
                           --->2.CSV
               ----->02-->21--->1.CSV
                           --->2.CSV
                      --->22--->1.CSV
                           --->2.CSV
               ...
```

As their are many csv files inside a particular date.
i want to combine all csv file inside each date folder with header of 1st file only into one single file and name is as orderno_year_month_date.csv.
means every datefolder will have have only one csv named after their parent folders.So,
i want clean command for this in linux which i can run outside of ORDERNO directory.

Expected structure should be like

```
ORDERNO'S  YEAR'S  MONTH'S  DATE'S  CSVFILES
408------->2010---->01-->21--->408_2010_01_21.CSV
                      --->22--->408_2010_01_22.CSV
                      ...
```

Previously i was going to each date folders of each month folder of each year folder of each order no. and use to run this command for single file for header.

```
awk '(NR == 1) || (FNR > 1)' *.csv > 4011_2020_07_16.csv  (example)
```

Comment: Please give an example of your expected structure.

Comment: Also; how sure are you that the structure of each CSV file within a particular date matches the structure of the first file?

Comment: @StephenBoston ihave updated please see.

Comment: @DanScally it exactly matches.Every file structure is exactly same.